# Getting Complete File Directory In Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I learned that I am possible to get the full path of the file by using `file.path`. But the format of path is not as I want.

```
C:\Users\FireIntrest\Desktop\...
```

Should I use `split()` to fix it, or there is a way to get the path with slashes?

```
C:/Users/FireIntrest/Desktop...
```

Comment: What about replacing every \ to `/`?

Comment: Yes, that can be a good way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath) to convert `Windows` paths to Unix-style forward slashes.

Given a path: `'c:\\windows\\nodejs\\path'`

`upath.normalize(path)`        --returns--> `'c:/windows/nodejs/path'`

There are methods like `upath.normalizeSafe(path)`

> Exactly like path.normalize(path), but it keeps the first meaningful
>   ./.

which may be useful/needed to preserve some of the leading path garbage that `Windows` gets up to